# How to register an OData Serializer Provider with AspNet.OData v6

Tags: asp.net, odata

Microsoft.AspNet.Odata changed the way you register services like serializers. What should the new format look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your new config should look something like this. You need to add at least the first 2 services (IEdmModel and IEnumerable IODataRoutingConvention), and then you can add your own. For example, a custom odata serializer provider.

```
using Boomerang.OData;
using Boomerang.Models;
using Microsoft.OData;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
using System.Web.OData.Formatter;
using System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization;
using System.Web.OData.Routing.Conventions;

namespace Boomerang
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                "ODataRoute",
                "api",
                containerBuilder => containerBuilder
                .AddService<IEdmModel>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => BuildEdmModelForOData())
                .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp =>
                    ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("ODataRoute", config))
                .AddService<ODataSerializerProvider>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => new CustomODataSerializerProvider(s))
                );

            config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
        }

        public static IEdmModel BuildEdmModelForOData()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder
                oDataConventionModelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

            // Build model here
            oDataConventionModelBuilder.EntitySet<Post>("Posts");
            oDataConventionModelBuilder.EntitySet<Feeling>("Feelings");

            return oDataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm adding this answer because most of the guides online give instructions for versions before 6. This information can be found here: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-04-DependencyInjection