# Ignore Null properties/values in Web Api with OData response Owin Self-Host

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, owin

I would like to Omit Null properties/values in Web Api with OData response Owin Self-Host Startup, in-order to reduce the content size.

I have 112 Controllers inheriting from a single abstract ApiController class, thus using a *CustomDirectRouteProvider*. (Not important)

I am running Framework 4.8 , NOT CORE.

I need help implementing a similar solution to [How to Ignore Null values while serializing OData response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863111/how-to-ignore-null-values-while-serializing-odata-response/52289266)

I have read pretty much all the posts on the subject and 'Stas Natalenko' solution seems to work fine for OData v3 and older but I am not sure how to implement 'Chris Schaller' solution for Odata v4 on self-host.

Here is my startup class:

```
public class CustomDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory>

    GetActionRouteFactories(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        // inherit route attributes decorated on base class controller's actions
        return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>
        (inherit: true);
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        using (var config = new HttpConfiguration())
        {
            config.EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyAPI"))
                .EnableSwaggerUi();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CustomDirectRouteProvider());
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

            config.AddODataQueryFilter();
            config.Formatters.Clear();

            config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null)
                .EnableDependencyInjection();

            config.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter
            {
                UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false,
                SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
                    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
                    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind,
                    Formatting = Formatting.None,
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                }
            });

            config.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.BsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my first ever question on StackOverFlow in my life. I've pretty much been clean all these years *facepalm*

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData` (Nuget) do you use?

Comment: Perhaps a long shot, but is it possible that these settings can be overridden in the MvcJsonOptions?

builder.Services.Configure<MvcJsonOptions>(opts => opts.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling......

Comment: @Julián latest stable available 7+

Comment: Not using MVC, only WebApi. In order for that to work will have to "app.UseMVC" or something and then inherit from an mvc controller instead of a api one.

Comment: I am trying to follow the solution you want, following the Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint on WebApi, but WebApiConfig.cs is supposed to be the app's startup file, usually Startup.cs I see it in MVC applications

Comment: @Julián not a problem, one can copy everything inside the WeApiConfig Register() and place it directly into Startup Configuration() Word-for-word. Try to write any answer to this question quickly, so I can award you 50 points.

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dealing two nights with a possible answer I think I have found a possible solution, however, the resources have the answer you mentioned, personally the part of **Dependency Injection** to register the serializer was the most difficult, but I must give credit to this question, it was helpful: [How to register an OData Serializer Provider with AspNet.OData v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257837/how-to-register-an-odata-serializer-provider-with-aspnet-odata-v6)

Finally I share what a solution could represent:

Following the **Microsoft documentation** for create the project:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

**1.** An **ASP .NET 4.7.2** project is created with **WebApi** template
**2.** Use the `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` package in its version `7.5.0`:

[image]

**3.** The controller is this:

```
public class ItemsController : ODataController
{
    public static List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item { Id = 1, Name = "name1", OptionalField = "Value Present" },
        new Item { Id = 3, Name = "name2" }
    };

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Item> Get()
    {
        return items.AsQueryable();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

According to the documentation this version of `OData` inherits from `ODataController` and `[Queryable]` represents an obsolete mark, that's why I use `[EnableQuery]`

**4.** In Models it was enough for me to replicate the solution to the question you are reacting (copying and pasting the `IngoreNullEntityPropertiesSerializerProvider` and `IngoreNullEntityPropertiesSerializer` classes in a new folder:

[image]

And the most difficult part, that of configuring the Serializer in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Configuración y servicios de API web

        // Rutas de API web
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", null, b => b
           .AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, typeof(IEdmModel), s => GetEdmModel())               
           .AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, typeof(IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>), s => ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("ODataRoute", config))              
           .AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, typeof(ODataSerializerProvider), sp => new IngoreNullEntityPropertiesSerializerProvider(sp))
        );
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<Item>("Items");        

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Finally the output of the Api:

*Input:*

```
public static List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item { Id = 1, Name = "name1", OptionalField = "Value Present" },
    new Item { Id = 3, Name = "name2" }
};
```

[image]

and with values:

*Input:*

```
public static List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item { Id = 1, Name = "name1", OptionalField = "Value Present" },
    new Item { Id = 3, Name = "name2",  OptionalField = "Value Present2" }
};
```

[image]

I hope this has been helpful.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted answer even though I haven't tested it. It was too late to manually award the bounty but I think it may still get auto-allocated in a few days...

Comment: Didn't work in my case, ODataController kept returning 406

Comment: I'll try again by stripping everything out and making everything bare minimum, btw you didn't use OWIN Self-host but you did give me some good insights.

Comment: Till today it haunts me that you didn't get your bounty in time. I will make it upto you one day Julián!

Comment: Relax, No problem bro :)